# Bulk insert in Mongodb and Postgresql

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, pymongo, psql

I am doing a comparison on `Postgresql` vs `Mongodb` on insert.I am using the `copy command` (from file to table) in `Postgresql` and i am wondering what is the equivalent command in `mongodb`.I think that the answer is the `insert_many(dict)`But i want be sure.Any advice would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert multiple documents in mongodb, you can use

```
db.collectionName.insertMany([{title: 'doc 1'},{title: 'doc2'},......]}
```